# display all Letter Tile Possibilities

Tags: javascript, c#, algorithm

I was doing the leetcode problem [Letter Tile Possibilities](https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-tile-possibilities/). Which is where you print out every possible sequence of a given string.

I have a working solution below. However, as a followup, I wanted to try and display all the sequences, but am having issues. Given string "AAB", it prints the correct number of sequences, but repeats several of the sequences, seen here:

[image]

**note**: B is a repeated sequence, and the sequence ABA never appears.

```
var numTilePossibilities = function (tiles) {
    let map = getTileMap(tiles);
    return helper(map, "");
};

function helper(map, currString) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let character in map) {
        if (map[character] !== 0) {
            sum++;
            currString += character;
            map[character] = map[character] - 1;
            sum += helper(map, currString);
            map[character] = map[character] + 1;
            console.log('completed string: ', currString);
            currString = '';
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I have found other solutions that I have edited to print out out all the sequences, and it prints correct, for example this c# solution:
[image]
[image]

But can't determine the difference between the solutions that is causing the sequences to print correctly.

How can I print out every string sequence for this problem?

Comment: the second example uses HashSet which will remove duplicates. You can use `Map` in Javascript for that, a simple object or find a better implementation

Comment: We'd give this out to C++ developers where the length of the input string was large enough so that the number of string combinations if stored in ram memory would exceed the RAM on the machine.

Comment: @stak what approach would the developer take at that point? First thing to reduce memory limits would be to make it iterative, other than that, I'm not sure. Check memory limits and warn the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the way that you modify `currString` after printing it. If you want to undo the appending of `character`, you should remove that character instead of setting the string to an empty string:

```
currString = currString.substring(0, currString.length - 1);
```

Perhaps it is better to leave `currString` as it is and create a new string only for the inner scope:

```
function helper(map, currString) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let character in map) {
        if (map[character] !== 0) {
            let newString = currString + character;            
            sum++;

            map[character] = map[character] - 1;
            sum += helper(map, newString);
            map[character] = map[character] + 1;

            console.log('completed string: ', newString);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: facepalm moment, thank you for your insight. Great answer.